# Can I use the at front of a place's or a building's name?

Tags: proper-nouns, noun-phrases

For example:

> the Zhong Nanhai.
>
> the Tiananmen Square.
>
> get to the Tiananmen Square

Is it ok?

Comment: We don't normally use an article before a name. "How do I get to Tiananmen Square?" There are exceptions: "How do I get to the American Cemetery?"

Comment: @WeatherVane https://apnews.com/48f8f727fd484ce89d49a5019916c431/France's-Macron-meets-Rihanna-at-the-Elysee-Palace

Comment: @WeatherVane but APNews uses "the" at front of a building's name. Is this a style of writing?

Comment: I am not sure if there is a *rule*, but something you get a feel for. Streets, roads and squares, etc, that have names, don't usually take an article. Buildings and other locations often do. Here is Tiananmen Square, there is London Road, this is the British Museum, the London Eye. But, that is Oxford University: no article, and I go shopping in the High Street: using article.